# Vim does not load colorscheme from .vimrc when started from tmux

Tags: command-line, vim, tmux

I got a very simple startup script, that starts a `gnome-terminal` with a running `tmux` session.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gnome-terminal -e "tmux" --window --full-screen
```

When I run `vim` inside this terminal, it does not load the colorscheme (`molokai`) I defined inside my `.vimrc`.

`echo $TERM` inside the `tmux` session gives me `screen-256color`.

`vim` and `tmux` work perfectly in all other teminals. Only when I run the given script the behavior differs from the expected one.

Comment: Try to compare the output of the vim commands `:scriptnames` and `:!set` when run in each way. The differences there should help you find the root cause.